# JSONPath Wildcard equivalent in Powershell to select all array in Object

Tags: json, powershell

I want to retrieve data from JSON file in Powershell. I have this JSON data:

```
{
  "id": "abcxyz",
  "data": {
    "a": {
        "abc": "xyz"
    },
    "b": [
      {
        "bId": 2001,
        "bData": {
          "bAbc": [
            {
              "bAbcX": 123,
              "bAbcY": 456,
              "bAbcZ": "b1AbcZ0"
            },
            {
              "bAbcX": 312,
              "bAbcY": 654,
              "bAbcZ": "b1AbcZ1"
            }
          ],
          "bDef": [
            {
              "bDefX": 456,
              "bDefY": 654,
              "bDefZ": "b1DefZ0"
            },
            {
              "bDefX": 789,
              "bDefY": 987,
              "bDefZ": "b1DefZ1"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bId": 2002,
        "bData": {
          "bAbc": [
            {
              "bAbcX": 123,
              "bAbcY": 456,
              "bAbcZ": "b2AbcZ0"
            },
            {
              "bAbcX": 312,
              "bAbcY": 654,
              "bAbcZ": "b2AbcZ1"
            }
          ],
          "bDef": [
            {
              "bDefX": 456,
              "bDefY": 654,
              "bDefZ": "b2DefZ0"
            },
            {
              "bDefX": 789,
              "bDefY": 987,
              "bDefZ": "b2DefZ1"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "bId": 2003,
        "bData": {
          "bAbc": [
            {
              "bAbcX": 123,
              "bAbcY": 456,
              "bAbcZ": "b3AbcZ0"
            },
            {
              "bAbcX": 312,
              "bAbcY": 654,
              "bAbcZ": "b3AbcZ1"
            }
          ],
          "bDef": [
            {
              "bDefX": 456,
              "bDefY": 654,
              "bDefZ": "b3DefZ0"
            },
            {
              "bDefX": 789,
              "bDefY": 987,
              "bDefZ": "b3DefZ1"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to retrieve data with JSONPath `$.data.b[*].bData.bAbc[0].bAbcZ` in Powershell. The expected result is:

```
[
  "b1AbcZ0",
  "b2AbcZ0",
  "b3AbcZ0"
]
```

The JSONPath is working in https://jsonpath.com/ and this is how I tried to retrieve it in powershell:

```
$JSON = Get-Content ".\test.json" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
$JSON.data.b[*].bData.bAbc[0].bAbcZ
```

But when I tried in Powershell, `*` is invalid, this is the output:

```
+ $JSON.data.b[*].bData.bAbc[0].bAbcZ
+              ~
Array index expression is missing or not valid.

+ $JSON.data.b[*].bData.bAbc[0].bAbcZ
+               ~
You must provide a value expression following the '*' operator.

+ $JSON.data.b[*].bData.bAbc[0].bAbcZ
+               ~
Unexpected token ']' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArrayIndexExpression
```

I also tried using `$JSON.data.b.bData.bAbc[0].bAbcZ` but it only retrieve the first data which is `b1AbcZ0`. What's the equivalent of JSON Wildcard (`*`) in Powershell object?

Comment: PowerShell as a .NET language doesn't support JSONPath out-of-the-box. You may use Newtonsoft JSON module [which does support JSONPath](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query similar to JSONPath by first **unrolling** the JSON object recursively. Then you can use the `Where-Object` command or `.Where{}` method to filter the JSON by path.

Here is a function to flatten the JSON. It outputs a sequence of `[PSCustomObject]` with properties `Path` and `Value`:

```sh
Function Expand-Json {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] $InputObject,
        [Parameter()] [string] $Path,
        [Parameter()] [string] $PathSeparator = '.',
        [Parameter()] [string] $IndexFormat = '<{0}>'
    )
    
    process {       
        if( $InputObject -is [Collections.IList] ) {
            # Iterate over array elements
            $i = 0
            foreach( $item in $InputObject ) {

                # Full path of current array item
                $itemPath = $Path + ($IndexFormat -f $i++)

                # Output current array item with path
                [PSCustomObject]@{ Path = $itemPath; Value = $item }

                if( $item -is [PSCustomObject] -or $item -is [Collections.IList] ) {
                    # Recurse into child container
                    Expand-Json -InputObject $item -Path $itemPath -PathSeparator $PathSeparator -IndexFormat $IndexFormat
                }
            }
        }
        elseif( $InputObject -is [PSCustomObject] ) {
            # Iterate over properties
            foreach( $prop in $InputObject.PSObject.Properties ) {

                # Full path of the current property
                $propertyPath = if( $Path ) { $Path, $prop.Name -join $PathSeparator } else { $prop.Name }

                # Output current property with path
                [PSCustomObject]@{ Path = $propertyPath; Value = $prop.Value }

                if( $prop.Value -is [PSCustomObject] -or $prop.Value -is [Collections.IList] ) {
                    # Recurse into child container
                    Expand-Json -InputObject $prop.Value -Path $propertyPath -PathSeparator $PathSeparator -IndexFormat $IndexFormat
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage example:**

```sh
$JSON = Get-Content ".\test.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

# Unroll the JSON
$flatJSON = $JSON | Expand-Json   

# Filter by path - this outputs an array
$filteredJSON = $flatJSON | Where-Object Path -like 'data.b<*>.bData.bAbc<0>.bAbcZ'

# Convert data back to JSON string
$filteredJSON.Value | ConvertTo-Json
```

**Output:**

```sh
[
  "b1AbcZ0",
  "b2AbcZ0",
  "b3AbcZ0"
]
```

**Notes:**

- The path syntax `data.b<*>.bData.bAbc<0>.bAbcZ` is slightly different from JSONPath to make it easier to use with the PowerShell `-like` operator.

  - There is no root object token `$`, because this character has special meaning for PowerShell string interpolation.
  - The array index is expressed using angular brackets `<>` by default, because square brackets `[]` have special meaning for the `-like` operator (they express a range of characters, see [about Wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2)). You may use `Expand-Json -IndexFormat '[{0}]'` to output square brackets anyway.
- The function `Expand-Json` is conceptually clear, but not very efficient. In general, recursive PowerShell functions tend to be comparatively slow because of the parameter binding overhead. If performance is paramount, there are several ways to improve performance considerably, e. g. by using a class or inline C#.

Answer (score 4):

It's sloppy but should do the trick. Just replace the .json file path in $JSONData.

```sh
$JSONData = Get-Content .\Documents\Untitled2.json |ConvertFrom-Json
$array = $JSONData.data.b.bdata.babc
$FinalArray = $JSONData.data.b.bdata | %{$_.bAbc[0].bAbcZ}
$FinalArray |Out-GridView
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Nice. You can streamline to: `$JSONData.data.b.bData.ForEach({ $_.bAbc[0].bAbcZ })`

Comment: As an aside: Since `ConvertFrom-Json` must read the file as a whole anyway, you can speed up the operation by adding the `-Raw` switch to the `Get-Content` call.