# Powershell: Recursively search JSON for a string in a value and return the path to the key

Tags: json, powershell, search

I want to use Powershell to recursively search a JSON for a string, and then have it report back the path to the value and what the value was.

In this example I want to search the whole JSON for any key that has 'corset' in its value, and then return back that it was found in :

- Data.RootChunk.appearances[0].Data.compiledData.Data.Chunk[0].mesh.DepotPath with the value "base\characters\garment\player_equipment\torso\t1_060_tank__corset\t1_060_pma_tank__corset.mesh",
- Data.RootChunk.appearances[0].Data.compiledData.Data.Chunk[0].name with the value t1_060_pma_tank__corset3513

Here is the C:\myFile.json file. It's only a partial for the full file, which is very long. For example, the full file has 20 records inside of Data.RootChunk.appearances[#]

```
{
    "Header": {
        "Version": "2022-10-28",
        "JsonVersion": "0.0.3"
    },
    "Data": {
        "Version": 195,
        "BuildVersion": 0,
        "RootChunk": {
            "$type": "appearanceAppearanceResource",
            "alternateAppearanceMapping": [],
            "alternateAppearanceSettingName": 0,
            "alternateAppearanceSuffixes": [],
            "appearances": [
                {
                    "HandleId": "0",
                    "Data": {
                        "$type": "appearanceAppearanceDefinition",
                        "censorFlags": 0,
                        "compiledData": {
                            "BufferId": "0",
                            "Data": {
                                "Version": 4,
                                "Sections": 7,
                                "CruidIndex": -1,
                                "CruidDict": {
                                    "0": 2050492557716705284
                                },
                                "Chunks": [
                                    {
                                        "$type": "entGarmentSkinnedMeshComponent",
                                        "acceptDismemberment": 1,
                                        "chunkMask": 18446744073709551615,
                                        "LODMode": "AlwaysVisible",
                                        "mesh": {
                                            "DepotPath": "base\\characters\\garment\\player_equipment\\torso\\t1_060_tank__corset\\t1_060_pma_tank__corset.mesh",
                                            "Flags": "Default"
                                        },
                                        "meshAppearance": "military_dirty",
                                        "name": "t1_060_pma_tank__corset3513",
                                        "navigationImpact": {
                                            "$type": "NavGenNavigationSetting",
                                            "navmeshImpact": "Ignored"
                                        },
                                        "order": 0,
                                        "overrideMeshNavigationImpact": 1,
                                        "parentTransform": {
                                            "HandleId": "1",
                                            "Data": {
                                                "$type": "entHardTransformBinding",
                                                "bindName": "root",
                                                "enabled": 1,
                                                "enableMask": {
                                                    "$type": "entTagMask",
                                                    "excludedTags": {
                                                        "$type": "redTagList",
                                                        "tags": [
                                                            "NoBinding"
                                                        ]
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "slotName": 0
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "forceCompileProxy": 0,
        "generatePlayerBlockingCollisionForProxy": 0,
        "partType": 0,
        "preset": 0,
        "proxyPolyCount": 1400,
        "Wounds": []
    }
}
```

The only success I've had is getting Powershell to show the full JSON. Converting the JSON to a hashtable causes its key-value information to drop, and for some reason I cannot get nested foreach or a recursive functions to drill into the JSON structure. I had the most promise with the recursive function, but it kept reporting back Header and Data as the results, it never even drilled down to the second layer.

```
$SourceFile = 'C:\myFile.json'
$Properties = Get-Content -Path $SourceFile | ConvertTo-Json
$Properties
```

Comment: jq has an operator `..` that's like xpath `//`, but I can't figure it out quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me offer another custom function, `Get-LeafProperty` (source code below):

Assuming it is already defined, you can call it as follows:

```
Get-Content -Raw C:\myFile.json | ConvertFrom-Json |
  Get-LeafProperty -FilterValue corset -MatchMode Substring
```

Output, based on your sample JSON (two `[pscustomobject]` instances with `.Path` and `.Value` properties):

```
Path                                                                          Value
----                                                                          -----
Data.RootChunk.appearances[0].Data.compiledData.Data.Chunks[0].mesh.DepotPath base\characters\garment\player_equipment\torso\t1_060_tank__corset\t1_060_pma_tank__corset.mesh
Data.RootChunk.appearances[0].Data.compiledData.Data.Chunks[0].name           t1_060_pma_tank__corset3513
```

---

**`Get-LeafProperty` source code**:

```
# Returns all leaf properties of an [pscustomobject] object graph 
# such as returned from ConvertFrom-Json as name-path-value pairs,
# optionally filtered by a leaf value.
# You can match by full value (by default), or by substring, wildcard pattern, 
# or regex, using the -MatchMode parameter. Add -CaseSensitive if needed.
# Note: A leaf property is a property whose value is neither a [pscustomobject]
#       nor an array, i.e. a value converted from a JSON primitive, namely
#       a string, Boolean, number, date, or $null.
function Get-LeafProperty {
  [CmdletBinding(PositionalBinding = $false)]
  param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory, Position = 0)] [AllowNull()] [object] $InputObject,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Filter')] [AllowNull()] $FilterValue,
    [ValidateSet('Full', 'Substring', 'Wildcard', 'Regex')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Filter')] $MatchMode = 'Full',
    [switch] $CaseSensitive,
    [string] $NamePath # used internally only
  )
  process {
    $null = $PSBoundParameters.Remove('InputObject'); $null = $PSBoundParameters.Remove('NamePath')
    if ($InputObject -is [array]) {
      # Recurse on the array's elements.
      $i = 0
      foreach ($o in $InputObject) { Get-LeafProperty -InputObject $o -NamePath ($NamePath + '[' + $i++ + ']') @PSBoundParameters }
    }
    elseif ($InputObject -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]) { 
      # A custom object: enumerate its properties / entries.
      $sep = '.' * ($NamePath -ne '')
      foreach ($p in $InputObject.psobject.properties) {
        Get-LeafProperty -InputObject $p.Value -NamePath ($NamePath + $sep + $p.Name) @PSBoundParameters
      }
    }
    else {
      # A leaf property (string, Boolean, number, date, or $null).
      # Report it along with its property path, but - if a filter value
      # was given - only if it matches that value.
      if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Filter') {
        $found = $false
        switch ($MatchMode) {
          'Full' {
            $found = if ($CaseSensitive) { $FilterValue -ceq $InputObject } else { $FilterValue -eq $InputObject }
            break
          }
          'Substring' {
            $found = 
            if ($CaseSensitive) { -1 -ne "$InputObject".IndexOf($FilterValue, [StringComparison]::InvariantCulture) }
            else { -1 -ne "$InputObject".IndexOf($FilterValue, [StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) }
            break
          }
          'Wildcard' {
            $found = if ($CaseSensitive) { $InputObject -clike $FilterValue } else { $InputObject -like $FilterValue }
            break
          }
          'Regex' {
            $found = if ($CaseSensitive) { $InputObject -cmatch $FilterValue } else { $InputObject -match $FilterValue } 
            break
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        $found = $true # no filtering
      }
      if ($found) {
        [pscustomobject] @{
          Path  = $NamePath
          Value = $InputObject
        }
      }
        
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Filtering by property *names* rather than *values***:

The above function only supports direct filtering by property *values*.

However, you can perform filtering by property *names* after the fact, using a [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) call; e.g., the following command extracts all path-value pairs whose path contains a `mesh` property:

```
Get-Content -Raw C:\myFile.json | ConvertFrom-Json |
  Get-LeafProperty |
  Where-Object Path -match '\bmesh\b'
```

Output, with your sample JSON:

```
Path                                                                          Value
----                                                                          -----
Data.RootChunk.appearances[0].Data.compiledData.Data.Chunks[0].mesh.DepotPath base\characters\garment\player_equipment\torso\t1_060_tank__corset\t1_060_pma_tank__corset.mesh
Data.RootChunk.appearances[0].Data.compiledData.Data.Chunks[0].mesh.Flags     Default
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use my function [`Expand-Json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73343519/7571258) to flatten the JSON and be able to search for values anywhere, using a simple `Where-Object` pipeline:

```sh
Get-Content -Path $SourceFile -Raw | 
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Expand-Json -IndexFormat '[{0}]' |
    Where-Object { $_.Value -is [string] -and $_.Value -match 'corset' } |
    ForEach-Object {
        '{0} with the value "{1}"' -f $_.Path, $_.Value
    }
```

**Output:**

```text
Data.RootChunk.appearances[0].Data.compiledData.Data.Chunks[0].mesh.DepotPath with the value "base\characters\garment\player_equipment\torso\t1_060_tank__corset\t1_060_pma_tank__corset.mesh"      
Data.RootChunk.appearances[0].Data.compiledData.Data.Chunks[0].name with the value "t1_060_pma_tank__corset3513"
```

**Note:**

- The default path format uses angular brackets for array indices, e. g. `item<0>`, which makes it easier to search for using PowerShell `-like` operator. In the example above, parameter `-IndexFormat` is used to specify square brackets, to match your desired output.

Comment: My code has your Expand-Json function and then below that is your recommendation. When I run it, there are no errors, but it also does not respond with anything. Are there any debug injections I can put into your code to see where the response is dropping? It's almost as if it's not finding the word "corset" but I've looked in the file and see it twice.

Comment: I selected your function and up to the Expand-Json in your recommended code. I get a table return of Path == .Length and Value == 33318. I tried running it again to include the Where-Object to search for 'corset' and that's where the response is empty.

Comment: @asdfasdf The function `Expand-Json` had some issues, e. g. an array at root level was not processed and it couldn't handle nested arrays. I've fixed the code in the linked answer and also made it easier to use by adding parameter `-IndexFormat` (see example in current answer). Please give it a try again! Even that you already accepted the other answer, I'm curious if the fixed code works for you.

Comment: @asdfasdf I just found out why you didn't get any output at all. I had used `ConvertTo-Json` while it should have been `ConvertFrom-Json`. ;-)

Comment: Those changes fixed the no-response problem, thank you :) I'm now getting the responses I would expect when I run your code.

Comment: @asdfasdf Thanks for confirming, despite that you already had a working answer! I think the code might still be useful for others, who have more complex filtering needs, which requires `Where-Object` anyways.

Comment: I repurposed some of your syntax for another block of code that filtered a list based on two other lists. So my gratitude holds :) This one question got two birds with one stone.

Answer (score 1):

Since the Q has the [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) tag, and since the solutions proposed elsewhere on this page so far seem so complicated, it may be worth noting two simple jq solutions.

```
paths as $p
| getpath($p) as $v
| select($v |strings|test("corset"))
| [$p, $v]
```

And using the `-—stream` command-line option:

```
select(length==2 and 
        (.[-1]|strings|test("corset")))
```

You can easily tailor the pretty-printing of the paths to your specifications.

Comment: Sorry about that @peak, a moderator must have added jq to the tags because I only added "json powershell search". I don't even know what jq is. I've since removed jq from the tags so it doesn't bait anyone else.

Comment: @asdfasdf I added the tag.  I thought there might be a simple jq solution with `..`.  Note that in powershell you have to backslash the doublequotes.